# Security Layer Above HTTPS

Tags: reactjs, encryption, https, server, frontend

I am about to start developing a website for clients `ReactJS`. This website will communicate with the server to retrieve sensitive data. The server is only accessed through `HTTPS` so it is safe. However, I am wondering if I should be adding an additional security layer by encrypting the data server sends and then decrypting that on the client side. I am going to use code scrambler so people (possibly) won't see what or how I decrypt. Or is it completely worthless doing that?

Anyone who's been in something similar before and can help me see through, please?
Thanks.

Comment: There's no need to do this.  HTTPS is enough.

Comment: Decrypting on the client will never work, since the client must necessarily have the key. As @LukeJoshuaPark said, HTTPS is sufficient, but you can encode your data if you at least want folks to jump through a hoop or two to get plaintext, after the SSL transfer is complete.